# How line ending conversions work with git core.autocrlf between different operating systems

Tags: git, newline, core.autocrlf

I've read a lot of different questions and answers on Stack Overflow as well as **git** documentation on how the **core.autocrlf** setting works.

This is my understanding from what I've read:

Unix and Mac OSX (pre-OSX uses CR) clients use LF line endings.
Windows clients use CRLF line endings.

When core.autocrlf is set to true on the client, the git repository always stores files in LF line ending format and line endings in files on the client are converted back and forth on check out / commit for clients (i.e. Windows) that use non-LF line endings, no matter what format the line endings files are on the client (this disagrees with Tim Clem's definition - see update below).

Here is a matrix that tries to document the same for the 'input' and 'false' settings of core.autocrlf with question marks where I'm not sure of line ending conversion behavior.

My questions are:

1. **What should the question marks be?**
2. **Is this matrix correct for the "non-question marks"?**

I'll update the question marks from the answers as consensus appears to be formed.

```
                       core.autocrlf value
            true            input              false
----------------------------------------------------------
commit   |  convert           ?                  ?
new      |  to LF      (convert to LF?)   (no conversion?)

commit   |  convert to        ?                 no 
existing |  LF         (convert to LF?)     conversion

checkout |  convert to        ?                 no
existing |  CRLF       (no conversion?)     conversion
```

I'm not really looking for opinions on the pros and cons of the various settings.  I'm just looking for data which makes it clear how to expect git to operate with each of the three settings.

--

**Update 04/17/2012**: After reading [the article by Tim Clem](https://adaptivepatchwork.com/2012/03/01/mind-the-end-of-your-line/) linked by JJD in the comments, I have modified some of the values in the "unknown" values in the table above, as well as changing "checkout existing | true to convert to CRLF instead of convert to client".  Here are the definitions he gives, which are more clear than anything I've seen elsewhere:

**core.autocrlf = false**

> This is the default, but most people are encouraged to change this
> immediately. The result of using false is that Git doesn’t ever mess
> with line endings on your file. You can check in files with LF or CRLF
> or CR or some random mix of those three and Git does not care. This
> can make diffs harder to read and merges more difficult. Most people
> working in a Unix/Linux world use this value because they don’t have
> CRLF problems and they don’t need Git to be doing extra work whenever
> files are written to the object database or written out into the
> working directory.

**core.autocrlf = true**

> This means that Git will process all text files and make sure that
> CRLF is replaced with LF when writing that file to the object database
> and turn all LF back into CRLF when writing out into the working
> directory. This is the recommended setting on Windows because it
> ensures that your repository can be used on other platforms while
> retaining CRLF in your working directory.

**core.autocrlf = input**

> This means that Git will process all text files and make sure that
> CRLF is replaced with LF when writing that file to the object
> database. It will not, however, do the reverse. When you read files
> back out of the object database and write them into the working
> directory they will still have LFs to denote the end of line. This
> setting is generally used on Unix/Linux/OS X to prevent CRLFs from
> getting written into the repository. The idea being that if you pasted
> code from a web browser and accidentally got CRLFs into one of your
> files, Git would make sure they were replaced with LFs when you wrote
> to the object database.

Tim's article is excellent, the only thing I can think of that is missing is that he assumes the repository is in LF format, which is not necessarily true, especially for Windows only projects.

Comparing Tim's article to the highest voted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4425433/147511) to date by jmlane shows perfect agreement on the true and input settings and disagreement on the false setting.

Comment: Keeping `autocrlf` to false seems so much easier ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333424/distributing-git-configuration-with-the-code/2354278#2354278

Comment: @VonC: I've read that and I think I understand it, but I don't necessarily get to make the choice.  I work with git repositories that I don't control who require that I set the value in a certain way.

Comment: @Michael: and, depending on the Git server version, the rules about eol and autocrlf are about to change in the upcoming 1.7.2! See http://article.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel/1007412

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice if Windows normalised to LF too? Mac used to be CR (prior v10) but is now normalised to LF.

Comment: I need to add a link to the great article of **Timothy Clem** - please read all of [Mind the End of Your Line](http://timclem.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/mind-the-end-of-your-line/).

Comment: Scenario: I'm a split Linux/Windows developer. I only use text editors that can recognize both types of line endings (IE. vim, eclipse). I only need (want) to work with files ending in LF. I currently have core.autocrlf=input set in my global git config. Am I good to go? Will I ever have a conflict?

Comment: It also seems to be [here](https://adaptivepatchwork.com/2012/03/01/mind-the-end-of-your-line/)

Comment: Related: [Disable git EOL Conversions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21822650/disable-git-eol-conversions)

Answer (score 159):

The best explanation of how `core.autocrlf` works is found on the [gitattributes](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) man page, in the [`text` attribute section](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_text).

This is how `core.autocrlf` appears to work currently (or at least since v1.7.2 from what I am aware):

- `core.autocrlf = true`

1. Text files checked-out from the repository that have only `LF` characters are normalized to `CRLF` in your working tree; files that contain `CRLF` in the repository will not be touched
2. Text files that have only `LF` characters in the repository, are normalized from `CRLF` to `LF` when committed back to the repository. Files that contain `CRLF` in the repository will be committed untouched.

- `core.autocrlf = input`

1. Text files checked-out from the repository will keep original EOL characters in your working tree.
2. Text files in your working tree with `CRLF` characters are normalized to `LF` when committed back to the repository.

- `core.autocrlf = false`

1. `core.eol` dictates EOL characters in the text files of your working tree.
2. `core.eol = native` by default, which means working tree EOLs will depend on where git is running: `CRLF` on a Windows machine, or `LF` in *nix.
3. Repository `gitattributes` settings determines EOL character normalization for commits to the repository (default is normalization to `LF` characters).

I've only just recently researched this issue and I also find the situation to be very convoluted. The `core.eol` setting definitely helped clarify how EOL characters are handled by git.

Comment: for autocrlf=true shouldn't be the following? Text files that have only CRLF EOL characters in the repository, are normalized from CRLF to LF when committed back to the repository. Files that contain LF in the repository will be committed untouched.

Comment: For me, even if autocrlf=false git was converting the EOL to CRLF. After reading this answer I realized that my .gitattribute file had text=auto set which was causing the trouble.

Comment: For `core.autocrlf = false`, if I don't have a `gitattributes` file does it mean that there will be no normalization? Or does it mean it will use the default normalization?

Comment: Shouldn't `.gitattributes` file take precedence over `core.autocrlf` setting?

Comment: it should be noted that after changing this setting, it helps to `git rm --cached -r .` and then `git reset --hard` in order to rewrite all files in the working tree. You will lose uncommitted changes by doing this!

Comment: @irsis got it right; as @jmlane states, when `autocrlf=false`, *"`core.eol` **dictates** EOL characters in the `text` files of your working tree…"*. In fact, even the ***least meddlesome*** git config, which is `autocrlf=input`, still entails (again, thanks to `core.eol`) *"[`CRLF → LF`] when committed…"*, meaning you can't simply add a new `CRLF` file into the repo *as-is*. The real culprit is what's designating various files for such abuse in the first place…, namely the `.gitattributes` entry `* text[=auto]`. If you want git to leave your files alone, start by disabling that: `* -text`.

Answer (score 81):

The issue of EOLs in mixed-platform projects has been making my life miserable for a long time. The problems usually arise when there are already files with different and mixed EOLs *already* in the repo. This means that:

1. The repo may have different files with different EOLs
2. Some files in the repo may have mixed EOL, e.g. a combination of `CRLF` and `LF` in the same file.

How this happens is not the issue here, but it does happen.

I ran some conversion tests on Windows for the various modes and their combinations.
Here is what I got, in a slightly modified table:

```
                 | Resulting conversion when       | Resulting conversion when 
                 | committing files with various   | checking out FROM repo - 
                 | EOLs INTO repo and              | with mixed files in it and
                 |  core.autocrlf value:           | core.autocrlf value:           
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
File             | true       | input      | false | true       | input | false
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Windows-CRLF     | CRLF -> LF | CRLF -> LF | as-is | as-is      | as-is | as-is
Unix -LF         | as-is      | as-is      | as-is | LF -> CRLF | as-is | as-is
Mac  -CR         | as-is      | as-is      | as-is | as-is      | as-is | as-is
Mixed-CRLF+LF    | as-is      | as-is      | as-is | as-is      | as-is | as-is
Mixed-CRLF+LF+CR | as-is      | as-is      | as-is | as-is      | as-is | as-is
```

As you can see, there are 2 cases when conversion happens on commit (3 left columns). In the rest of the cases the files are committed as-is.

Upon checkout (3 right columns), there is only 1 case where conversion happens when:

1. `core.autocrlf` is `true` *and*
2. the file in the repo has the `LF` EOL.

Most surprising for me, and I suspect, the cause of many EOL problems is that there is no configuration in which mixed EOL like `CRLF`+`LF` get normalized.

Note also that "old" Mac EOLs of `CR` only also never get converted.
This means that if a badly written EOL conversion script tries to convert a mixed ending file with `CRLF`s+`LF`s, by just converting `LF`s to `CRLF`s, then it will leave the file in a mixed mode with "lonely" `CR`s wherever a `CRLF` was converted to `CRCRLF`.
Git will then not convert anything, even in `true` mode, and EOL havoc continues. This actually happened to me and messed up my files really badly, since some editors and compilers (e.g. VS2010) don't like Mac EOLs.

I guess the only way to really handle these problems is to *occasionally* normalize the whole repo by checking out all the files in `input` or `false` mode, running a proper normalization and re-committing the changed files (if any). On Windows, presumably resume working with `core.autocrlf true`.

Comment: Excellent answer, but one sentence with whom I cannot agree is _On Windows, presumably resume working with `core.autocrlf true`_. I personally believe that `input` should be used always.

Answer (score 80):

The `core.autocrlf` value does not depend on the operating system,
but the default value is `true` on Windows. On Linux it is `input`.
I explored three possible values for the checkout and commit cases.

Here is the resulting table :

```
╔═══════════════╦══════════════╦══════════════╦══════════════╗
║ core.autocrlf ║     false    ║     input    ║     true     ║
╠═══════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╣
║               ║ LF   => LF   ║ LF   => LF   ║ LF   => CRLF ║
║ git checkout  ║ CR   => CR   ║ CR   => CR   ║ CR   => CR   ║
║               ║ CRLF => CRLF ║ CRLF => CRLF ║ CRLF => CRLF ║
╠═══════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╣
║               ║ LF   => LF   ║ LF   => LF   ║ LF   => LF   ║
║ git commit    ║ CR   => CR   ║ CR   => CR   ║ CR   => CR   ║
║               ║ CRLF => CRLF ║ CRLF => LF   ║ CRLF => LF   ║
╚═══════════════╩══════════════╩══════════════╩══════════════╝
```

Comment: Shorty summary in words: Files with `CR` alone are never touched. `false` never touches line endings. `true` always commits as `LF` and checks out as `CRLF`. And `input` always commits as `LF` and checks out as-is.

Comment: @pratt it __does__ depend on the Operating System ->when `autocrlf = false` and `eol=native`.

Answer (score 41):

Things are about to change on the "eol conversion" front, with the [upcoming Git 1.7.2](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel/1007412):

A new config setting [**`core.eol`** is being added/evolved](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/PATCH-v6-Add-quot-core-eol-quot-config-variable-td5140844.html):

> This is a replacement for the 'Add "`core.eol`" config variable' commit that's currently in `pu` (the last one in my series).
>   Instead of implying that "`core.autocrlf=true`" is a replacement for "`* text=auto`", **it makes explicit the fact that `autocrlf` is only for users who want to work with
>   CRLFs in their working directory on a repository that doesn't have text
>   file normalization**.
>   When it is enabled, "core.eol" is ignored.
>
> Introduce a new configuration variable, "`core.eol`", that allows the user to set which line endings to use for end-of-line-normalized files in the working directory.
>   It defaults to "`native`", which means CRLF on Windows and LF everywhere else.
>   Note that "`core.autocrlf`" overrides `core.eol`.
>   This means that:
>
> ```
> [core]
>   autocrlf = true
> ```
>
> puts CRLFs in the working directory even if `core.eol` is set to "`lf`".
>
> ```
> core.eol:
> ```
>
> Sets the line ending type to use in the working directory for files that have the `text` property set.
>   Alternatives are 'lf', 'crlf' and 'native', which uses the platform's native line ending.
>   The default value is `native`.

---

Other evolutions [are being considered](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/PATCH-v3-0-5-End-of-line-normalization-redesigned-tp5043832p5060046.html):

> For 1.8, I would consider making `core.autocrlf` just turn on normalization and leave the working directory line ending decision to core.eol, but that *will* break people's setups.

---

git 2.8 (March 2016) improves the way `core.autocrlf` influences the eol:

See [commit 817a0c7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/817a0c7968c1d7e0f574b6d07451445832f781aa) (23 Feb 2016), [commit 6e336a5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6e336a530b0dd98d1c751440ca5666a6999ab020), [commit df747b8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/df747b818f0c9b7d0db1d7e3837b78e5d48b6fde), [commit df747b8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/df747b818f0c9b7d0db1d7e3837b78e5d48b6fde) (10 Feb 2016), [commit df747b8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/df747b818f0c9b7d0db1d7e3837b78e5d48b6fde), [commit df747b8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/df747b818f0c9b7d0db1d7e3837b78e5d48b6fde) (10 Feb 2016), and [commit 4b4024f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4b4024f5ddca2ac14c2b15158d7cca888a8ae25e), [commit bb211b4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bb211b4de83b7cbc93049bc0d73883083a6a8b0b), [commit 92cce13](https://github.com/git/git/commit/92cce1355ed4d2eb674b0742b00cfa133a4a8d58), [commit 320d39c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/320d39cdb075896804868cc8b1ca834a04ffdd8f), [commit 4b4024f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4b4024f5ddca2ac14c2b15158d7cca888a8ae25e), [commit bb211b4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bb211b4de83b7cbc93049bc0d73883083a6a8b0b), [commit 92cce13](https://github.com/git/git/commit/92cce1355ed4d2eb674b0742b00cfa133a4a8d58), [commit 320d39c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/320d39cdb075896804868cc8b1ca834a04ffdd8f) (05 Feb 2016) by [Torsten Bögershausen (`tboegi`)](https://github.com/tboegi).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c6b94eb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c6b94eb0093216f7a02a8c7a350d1760478a52a1), 26 Feb 2016)</sup>

> ### `convert.c`: refactor `crlf_action`
>
> Refactor the determination and usage of `crlf_action`.
>   Today, when no "`crlf`" attribute are set on a file, `crlf_action` is set to
>   `CRLF_GUESS`. Use `CRLF_UNDEFINED` instead, and search for "`text`" or "`eol`" as before.
>
> Replace the old `CRLF_GUESS` usage:

```
CRLF_GUESS && core.autocrlf=true -> CRLF_AUTO_CRLF
CRLF_GUESS && core.autocrlf=false -> CRLF_BINARY
CRLF_GUESS && core.autocrlf=input -> CRLF_AUTO_INPUT
```

> Make more clear, what is what, by defining:

```
- CRLF_UNDEFINED : No attributes set. Temparally used, until core.autocrlf
                   and core.eol is evaluated and one of CRLF_BINARY,
                   CRLF_AUTO_INPUT or CRLF_AUTO_CRLF is selected
- CRLF_BINARY    : No processing of line endings.
- CRLF_TEXT      : attribute "text" is set, line endings are processed.
- CRLF_TEXT_INPUT: attribute "input" or "eol=lf" is set. This implies text.
- CRLF_TEXT_CRLF : attribute "eol=crlf" is set. This implies text.
- CRLF_AUTO      : attribute "auto" is set.
- CRLF_AUTO_INPUT: core.autocrlf=input (no attributes)
- CRLF_AUTO_CRLF : core.autocrlf=true  (no attributes)
```

---

As [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206843/how-line-ending-conversions-work-with-git-core-autocrlf-between-different-operat/3209806?noredirect=1#comment71852526_3209806):

> all these translations (any EOL conversion from `eol=` or `autocrlf` settings, and "`clean`" filters) **are run when files move from work-tree to index**, i.e., during `git add` rather than at `git commit` time.
>   (Note that `git commit -a` or `--only` or `--include` do add files to the index at that time, though.)

For more on that, see "[What is difference between autocrlf and eol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42351446/6309)".

Comment: This, unfortunately, doesn't add clarity for me.  It seems like they are saying there are problems with the current implementation (it's not clear what those problems are) and they are increasing the complexity in an effort to solve those unspecified problems.  In my opinion, the core.autocrlf setting is already overly complex and under-documented and that situation appears to be getting worse.  Thanks again for the heads up.

Comment: This does not seem like a satisfactory solution, and seems to have the same problems as core.autocrlf. My preference would be if git would never automatically modify anything, but it would warn the user who wants to add or commit the wrong line endings. So you would need a commandline option to allow "git add" to add the "wrong" line endings. (probably git add is the better place to check this than git commit)

Comment: This would force the respective user to change their editor settings and really take care of the problem. While it would allow to leave the "wrong" line endings for files from 3rd parties, or that are already checked into the repository.

Comment: @donquixote again, I agree. But `core.eol` is about "automatically modifying" only what you explicitly *declare* in a `.gitattributes` file. This is different from `core.autocrlf` which applies to *any* file in the repo. It is a declarative process.

Comment: ah, ok. So if I Understand correctly, if .gitattributes is empty, core.autocrlf will assume some default file types to always convert, whereas core.eol will assume nothing. But once you create a .gitattributes, then both core.eol and core.autocrlf will behave the same?

Comment: And yes you agree, but I still wanted to say this here because it seems a more relevant place to say it than in the other question.

Comment: @donquixote: I realize this is quite old but I only read your comment now. In fact, all these translations (any EOL conversion from eol= or autocrlf settings, *and* "clean" filters) are run when files move from work-tree to index, i.e., during `git add` rather than at `git commit` time. (Note that `git commit -a` or `--only` or `--include` do add files to the index at that time, though.) For what it's worth, you and I and Linus Torvalds all hate the idea of a VCS *ever* modifying what's being committed. But there are all those Windows users... :-)

Comment: @torek Thank you for the comment. I have included it in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: That's a great post. Thanks for all the in depth clarification.
However, I have one question that still remains unanswered (at least to me).
I want to enforce autocrlf=input through the gitattributes file, how can I do that?

Comment: @laertis You would need a core.eol directive, associated to '*' (for all the files) See https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#gitattributes-Settostringvaluelf: `eol=lf` if you are on Linux.

Comment: @VonC if my understanding is correct, `core.eol` implies that every files associated with that filter would have its line endings converted to `lf` in my working directory. I don't want that. What I want is to checkout `as is` and commit with `lf` which is what `core.autocrlf=input` does if my understanding is correct again.

Comment: @laertis I agree. That means core.eol might not be the right tool.

Comment: @VonC which brings us back to my original question. Is there a way to enforce `core.autocrlf=input` from within the `.gitattributes` in order to propagate the policy throughtout my colleagues ?

Comment: @laertis Good question; could you ask it as an independent one, since I am not sure of the answer based of what is documented above?

Comment: @VonC Thanks for the immediate responses. I just did post an independent question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42667996/enforce-core-autocrlf-input-through-gitattributes

Answer (score 10):

Here is my understanding of it so far, in case it helps someone.

`core.autocrlf=true` and `core.safecrlf = true`

You have a **repository where all the line endings are the same**, but you work on different platforms. Git will make sure your lines endings are converted to the default for your platform. Why does this matter? Let's say you create a new file. The text editor on your platform will use its default line endings. When you check it in, if you don't have core.autocrlf set to true, you've introduced a line ending inconsistency for someone on a platform that defaults to a different line ending. I always set safecrlf too because I would like to know that the crlf operation is reversible. With these two settings, **git is modifying your files, but it verifies that the modifications are reversible**.

`core.autocrlf=false`

You have a **repository that already has mixed line endings** checked in and fixing the incorrect line endings could break other things. Its best not to tell git to convert line endings in this case, because then it will exacerbate the problem it was designed to solve - making diffs easier to read and merges less painful. With this setting, **git doesn't modify your files**.

`core.autocrlf=input`

I don't use this because the reason for this is to cover a use case where you created a file that has CRLF line endings on a platform that defaults to LF line endings. I prefer instead to make my text editor always save new files with the platform's line ending defaults.

Answer (score 6):

No, the @jmlane answer is wrong.

#### For `Checkin (git add, git commit)`:

1. if `text` property is `Set, Set value to 'auto'`, the conversion happens enen the file has been committed with 'CRLF'
2. if `text` property is `Unset`:nothing happens, enen for `Checkout`
3. if `text` property is `Unspecified`, conversion  depends on `core.autocrlf`

   1. if `autocrlf = input or autocrlf = true`, the conversion only happens when the file in the repository is 'LF', if it has been 'CRLF', nothing will happens.
   2. if `autocrlf = false`, nothing happens

#### For `Checkout`:

1. if `text` property is `Unset`: nothing happens.
2. if `text` property is `Set, Set value to 'auto`: it depends on `core.autocrlf`, `core.eol`.

   1. core.autocrlf = input : nothing happens
   2. core.autocrlf = true : the conversion only happens when the file in the repository is 'LF', 'LF' -> 'CRLF'
   3. core.autocrlf = false : the conversion only happens when the file in the repository is 'LF', 'LF' -> `core.eol`
3. if `text` property is `Unspecified`, it depends on `core.autocrlf`.

   1. the same as `2.1`
   2. the same as `2.2`
   3. None, nothing happens, core.eol is not effective when `text` property is `Unspecified`

#### Default behavior

So the Default behavior is `text` property is `Unspecified` and `core.autocrlf = false`:

1. for checkin, nothing happens
2. for checkout, nothing happens

#### Conclusions

1. if `text` property is set, checkin behavior is depends on itself, not on autocrlf
2. autocrlf or core.eol is for checkout behavior, and autocrlf > core.eol

Answer (score 3):

Did some tests both on linux and windows. I use a test file containing lines ending in LF and also lines ending in CRLF.
File is committed , removed and then checked out.
The value of core.autocrlf is set before commit and also before checkout.
The result is below.

```
commit core.autocrlf false, remove, checkout core.autocrlf false: LF=>LF   CRLF=>CRLF  
commit core.autocrlf false, remove, checkout core.autocrlf input: LF=>LF   CRLF=>CRLF  
commit core.autocrlf false, remove, checkout core.autocrlf true : LF=>LF   CRLF=>CRLF  
commit core.autocrlf input, remove, checkout core.autocrlf false: LF=>LF   CRLF=>LF  
commit core.autocrlf input, remove, checkout core.autocrlf input: LF=>LF   CRLF=>LF  
commit core.autocrlf input, remove, checkout core.autocrlf true : LF=>CRLF CRLF=>CRLF  
commit core.autocrlf true, remove, checkout core.autocrlf false: LF=>LF   CRLF=>LF  
commit core.autocrlf true, remove, checkout core.autocrlf input: LF=>LF   CRLF=>LF  
commit core.autocrlf true,  remove, checkout core.autocrlf true : LF=>CRLF CRLF=>CRLF
```

Answer (score 2):

The statement `core.autocrlf=true` leading to `CRLF -> LF` on commit is all wrong!  It's not all that simple, as you'll see...

The [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coreautocrlf) say the setting corresponds to... “`text=auto` in `.gitattributes` and `core.eol` being set to `crlf` in git config” ...meaning what exactly?

Meaning that, if a file does not have a `.gitattributes` **text** attribute set, and if `core.autocrlf` is `true`, it now depends on whether you the file being committed is new (in that case, yes, it will get normalized to LF in the git repo database), or whether it was an existing file that you edited and are now committing (in which case NOTHING will happen... unless you run `git add --renormalize .` in which case it will get normalized in the git repo database).

You see... the whole mechanism only happens to a file for which a `.gitattributes` has **not** placed a variant of the text attribute: `text`, `-text`, `text=auto`.

So what you should really be looking at is using `.gitattributes` with a default setting on all your files, being either:

```sh
* -text
# followed by specialization
```

which will default all (except specializations) to ***as-is***, and overriding `core.autocrlf` completely, or using a default of:

```sh
*  text=auto
# followed by specialization
```

meaning that all files (except specializations) that git auto-detects as non-binary (text), and which have `LF` in the git database<sup>[see note 1.]</sup>, will get `CRLF` whenever:
    • `core.autocrlf` is `true`, or
    • `core.eol` is `crlf`, or
    • `core.eol` is `native` (default) and you're on a Windows platform.
In all other cases, you get `LF`.

What specializations do I mean? For example having `.bat` files be `CRLF` and `.sh` files be `LF` via either:

```sh
*.sh           text eol=lf

# *.bat
*.[bB][aA][tT] text eol=crlf
```

or

```sh
# *.sh are committed correctly as-is (LF)
*.sh           -text

# *.bat are committed correctly as-is (CRLF)
*.[bB][aA][tT] -text
```

So yes... it's all not so simple.

---

[note 1]:
This will be the case for all files matching the `text=auto` attribute (i.e. not having some other specialization), since I assume your repo was properly normalized when the `.gitattribute` was created