# git trying to convert LF to CRLF on ubuntu with core.autocrlf set to true

Tags: git, configuration, core.autocrlf

I'm using git on ubuntu with autocrlf set to true. My editor is configured to use LF as end-of-line character. After I edited a file and did

```
git add .
```

I got :

```
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in file1.txt. (1)
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory. (2)
```

As to (1), why git would want to convert my LF in my file into CRLF? Should it work exactly the way around that only when your file contains CRLF and only then git will try to convert CRLF to LF?

As to (2), does that mean the file I'm looking at will still go with only LF but the snapshot in git's staging area is converted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the warning message, I am guessing your configuration is the following:

- You are using windows with `core.eol` set to `native` (default in git 1.7.2 and above) or have explicitly set core.eol to `crlf`
- Your core.autocrlf is set to `input`

These `git attributes`, `core.autocrlf` and `core.eol` let you configure what you want for line endings and their possible values and what they mean is captured in the git man page and [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4425433/55562)

And the answer to both (1) and (2), your questions is, "Because you configured it so"

What you should do depends on what platform you are on, and what other platform you would access git from. It is recommended to let git store only `LF` as the end of line, as the blob hash generated would change otherwise and git would complain of "changed lines" even when thee change may  be only of the line end characters.

Since you are on Ubuntu, you want to set `core.eol` to `lf` and `core.autocrlf` to `input` so that git does not convert LF to CRLF in your working tree.

Comment: Nope, I'm using ubuntu. I'm sure the configuration for core.autocrlf is true.

Comment: If you are on Ubuntu, forget all else and make core.autocrlf into input. That is, if no one else uses it on windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not doing cross-platform development (in particular, with Windows), set autocrlf to false and have people you work with do the same. There is no need to alter files before they are made into objects in git. It is a huge hassle. I have never dealt with this issue anymore in 4 years of using git. Unless you ARE doing x-platform *with Windows*, set to false. Easy fix.