# Why am I getting ": No such file or directory" when trying to execute a bash script?

Tags: git, bash, shell

I'm trying to execute a bash script (git-ftp) but I can't seem to do it. This is what happens:

```
[trusktr@rocketship ~]$ ~/scripts/git-ftp
: No such file or directory
```

The file has permissions 755.

This is the contents of the script: http://pastie.org/3567556

Why am I getting this error? What can I do to fix the problem?

Comment: Does `ls ~/scripts/git-ftp` work?

Comment: If you're like me, after reading the answer to this question you might want to look at [How line ending conversions work with git core.autocrlf between different operating systems](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3206843/1157054).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I have seen this error if the script has windows line endings instead of unix line endings. Try running `dos2unix` on the script and see if you get the same error.

Comment: Wow, interesting. That was exactly it.

Comment: You mean that exact error with the colon:   <empty>: no such file or directory.  Makes sense; an empty command. It's not actually empty but the string `"\r"`  The leading carriage return disappears when printed since on your Unix terminal it just moves the cursor to column 0.

Comment: @Kaz: It's more complicated than that.  The shebang line in the script is `#!/usr/bin/env bash\r`, so env prints the error "env: bash\r: No such file or directory".  The carriage return makes the second part (": No such file or directory") overwrite the first part, so you don't see the first part.  (p.s.: well spotted, joesdiner.)

Answer (score 1):

Is there a `#!` (hash bang) line in the script, and does the pathname resolve?

If the script is running, it may be something in the script. Add this command to the top of the script, before any other command (but of course after the hash bang, if there is one):

```
set -x   # enable trace mode
```

Comment: Yeah, if you look at the script, it has "#!/usr/bin/env bash" at the top. I tried adding `set -x` but nothing new happens.

Comment: Try `bash -x ~/scripts/git-ftp` and see if that reveals anything.  FWIW the script runs fine for me printing the usage message

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me. Turns out @joesdiner was exactly right: I needed to convert all line endings to unix style.