# cd to directory not working in shell script

Tags: shell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why am I getting “: No such file or directory” when trying to execute a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9651406/why-am-i-getting-no-such-file-or-directory-when-trying-to-execute-a-bash-scr)

I have the following shell script..when running it the cd command keeps failing with below error..can anyone provide inputs what is wrong?

```
#\!/bin/sh
ANDROID_ROOT="/local/mnt/workspace/AU"
cd $ANDROID_ROOT 
source build/envsetup.sh                                     
lunch 12

: No such file or directoryal/mnt/workspace/AU
./test.sh: line 4: build/envsetup.sh: No such file or directory
<username:/local/mnt/workspace/username/scripts>
```

Comment: Did you try doing cd at the command prompt? Also, remove the \ in the 1st line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line endings are goofed up. Run it through `dos2unix`.

Comment: Yes, you are right,i just figured that out..thnaks