# git line ending option in ubuntu 12.04 virtual box vm for shared folder on my mac

Tags: macos, git, ubuntu, virtualbox, line-endings

I am running ubuntu 12 VM using virtual box on my mac. I have cloned a git repo in a shared folder on my mac. From that folder, in my ubuntu VM, i am creating a intellij project. Trouble is, when i create that project it marks all the files as changed with no change in contents(possibly due to different line ending). How can this be avoided? I have this configuration in .gitconfig on my mac and ubuntu vm autocrlf = input.

Can someone suggest the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Check that you are using git on host machine and then try to set core.autocrlf to false:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

Reset all 'changes' to head with:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

Also check that your git has disabled handling for filemode changes

```
git config --list
```

Should be

> core.filemode=false

If not, then set it with:

```
git config --global core.filemode false
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest was is to desactive that setting:

```
git config --auto auto.crlf false
```

(on your mac)

If your IDE (here IntelliJ) doesn't change the line endings, there is no need to impose a global settings changing *all* the files.

If some files *have* to keep a specific line ending, use `core.eol` directive in a `.gitattributes` file (which isn't a local config, but a file part of your repo, and as such, pushed and pulled as the other files).

See "[How line ending conversions work with git core.autocrlf between different operating systems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3209806/6309)".