# Why are there cr characters in the output of a diff when there are none in the input?

Tags: git, diff, newline

I have a bare git repository on a linux machine, and I am pushing to it from a Windows machine and using a post-receive hook on the linux machine to check it out to a local folder.

On the Windows machine, I have `core.autocrlf=true`, and on the linux machine `core.autocrlf=input`.  I also have a .gitattributes file with the following contents:

```
* text=auto
*.csv text
```

On the linux machine I am diff'ing a csv file in the repository (generated by the Windows machine) with a non-repository file generated by the linux machine:

```
diff -iw -U0 repofile.csv localfile.csv > out.txt
```

When I open repofile.csv and localfile.csv separately in vi, for example, neither file has CR characters, which is what I want.  However, when I open out.txt, behold, there are CR characters at the end of each line involving a line from repofile.csv.

What gives?  I am completely mystified as to why CR characters would be showing up in the output of a diff when neither input file has CR characters in it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure **[`core.autocrlf` is `false`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2354278/6309)** on both servers: you don't want Git to modify automatically any file, unless you explicitly instructs Git (through the **[`core.eol .gitattributes` directives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3209806/6309)**).

Since `core.autocrlf` overrides `core.eol`, that can explain the CR you keep seeing.

Comment: This does not seem to fix the issue.  I still see no CRs in either the the diff'ed files, but I do see CRs in the diff output.