# git init - bad numeric config value 'auto' for 'core.autocrlf' in

Tags: git

Just started working with git 15 minutes ago and already trouble ... damn.

Well, just as i wrote in the headline, im currently working with the git-scm book here: http://git-scm.com/book

**In 2.1 - Getting a Git repository**, it says:

> If you’re starting to track an existing project in Git, you need to go
>   to the project’s directory and type

```
$ git init
```

Thats exactly what im doing, but somehow, i get this error message here:

```
fatal: bad numeric config value 'auto' for 'core.autocrlf' in C:\Program Files 
(x86)\Git(etc/gitconfig: invalid unit
```

I configured everything just as it says in the book ... im kinda helpless here, especially because i got absolutely no experience with git and google doesnt seem to be very helpful in that case. ._.

Edit: Heres a screenshot, maybe it helps you:

[image: ._.]

Comment: Did you manually change the configuration for Git, or is the configuration file exactly what you got from an installer?

Comment: Its the config i got from the installer. I never executed a config statement for autocrlf or something like that. I just adjusted my name and e-mail.

Comment: With a setting of "auto", I get the same error (well, I get "bad config value" instead of "bad numeric config value"), and the documentation doesn't give any indication that "auto" is a valid value, so if the installer does configure it like that, that seems like a problem with the installer.

Comment: Is manually changing the config file a problem? I have done for `[alias]` and `[color "status"]` within `~/.gitconfig`

Comment: No, it's really not a problem. ``git config`` does nothing else but edit the file, so you can do it yourself too. Just beware of typos, those are extremely hard to spot.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try a

```
git config --system --unset core.autocrlf
```

I would then advise for a:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

(see "[Why should I use core.autocrlf=true in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2825829/6309)"; using **[`core.eol` settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3209806/6309)** per files is more precise than using a repo-wide global setting)

You could set it back in the system config if you want:

```
git config --system core.autocrlf false
```

But the main point is 'auto' isn't a valid value: `true`, `false` or `input` are, as [detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4425433/6309).

---

[FernandoZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/226142/fernandoz) suggests [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21328687/git-init-bad-numeric-config-value-auto-for-core-autocrlf-in/21328799#comment88864503_21328799):

```
git config --global --replace-all core.autocrlf false
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you recommend moving the setting from the system file to the per-user global file?

Comment: @hvd I have edited the answer to reference why I recommend *not* using that legacy dangerous `core.autocrlf` setting.

Comment: When i try the first statement, i get the error message `fatal: No such section!` But when i enter `git config --list`, its there.

Comment: @VonC I don't mean whether a particular `core.autocrlf` value is a useful setting, I just mean I don't see why having `core.autocrlf = false` in the global config file is any better or worse than having `core.autocrlf = false` in the system config file, so I don't see why you removed it from the system config and added it to the global config.

Comment: BTW, as the error from Y U NO WORK indicates, `--remove-section` is the wrong option regardless, it should be `--unset`. `--remove-section` is for removing a whole section, such as `core`.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot, `--unset` and the second query of VonC did the trick. `Initialized empty Git repository in y:/.git/`. :)

Comment: @YUNOWORK I have edited the answer ti use unset, as hvd mentioned.

Comment: I was stuck unable to change this setting and ended up using

Comment: git config --global --replace all core.autocrlf false

Comment: @FernandoZ Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility. It is `--replace-all`, not `--replace all`.

Comment: Maybe: git config --system --unset-all core.autocrlf

Answer (score 1):

Commands from the console didn't help me.
Opened 3 config files (local system global) and removed the problematic value.
[image]

Comment: what's the value you removed?

Comment: parameter specified in the error text. I had a similar problem but with a different parameter.

Answer (score 1):

1. go to repo folder
2. open the `.git` folder
3. open the file `config`
4. remove duplicate entries

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked this way:

`git config --global commit.gpgsign false`