# Git Error: fatal: bad numeric config value 'falseexit' for 'core.trustctime': invalid unit

Tags: git

I am getting this error when using `git init` command and even for other commands like `git clone`.

```
git init
fatal: bad numeric config value 'falseexit' for 'core.trustctime': invalid unit
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git init - bad numeric config value 'auto' for 'core.autocrlf' in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21328687/git-init-bad-numeric-config-value-auto-for-core-autocrlf-in)

Answer (score 4):

I just ran the following:

```
git config --global commit.gpgsign true
```

Answer (score 1):

`core.trustctime` must be boolean: yes/no/1/0/true/false. You have an error in your git config file. Edit .gitconfig or .git/config and change *falseexit* to just *false*.

PS. *falseexit*, hm... seems someone has tried to [exit vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828270/how-to-exit-the-vim-editor) without switching from insert mode to normal mode.

Answer (score 0):

> `core.trustctime` must be boolean

With Git 2.31 (Q1 2021), the error message given when a configuration variable that is expected to have a boolean value has been improved.

See [commit f276e2a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f276e2a469430999ff7e3735ea7b41508ed1abd8) (11 Feb 2021) by [Andrew Klotz (`KlotzAndrew`)](https://github.com/KlotzAndrew).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 483e09e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/483e09e810796786baf7a9139680f6d2f2470829), 17 Feb 2021)</sup>

> ### [`config`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f276e2a469430999ff7e3735ea7b41508ed1abd8): improve error message for boolean config
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Andrew Klotz</sup>

> Currently invalid boolean config values return messages about '`bad numeric`', which is slightly misleading when the error was due to a boolean value.
>
> We can improve the developer experience by returning a boolean error message when we know the value is neither a `bool` text or `int`.
>
> Before with an invalid boolean value of `non-boolean`, its unclear what numeric is referring to:
>
> ```
> fatal: bad numeric config value 'non-boolean' for 'commit.gpgsign': invalid unit
> ```
>
> Now the error message mentions `non-boolean` is a bad boolean value:
>
> ```
> fatal: bad boolean config value 'non-boolean' for 'commit.gpgsign'
> ```