# fatal: bad boolean config value for 'core.autocrlf'

Tags: git

i am new to git and i am doing a test repository to see how it goes.

First when i did `git add` i had a warning telling me that my file will be turned to clrf or something like that.

So i tried to change it just to see what it does.

I did something like `git config core.autocrlf = false` What i did not expected is that the "=" would be passed as a value to this boolean.
It make's very little sens to me.

So i don't need = to assign a value to a variable fine. I did it again this time `git config core.autocrlf false`

Then i did `git add` and get the following message :fatal: bad boolean config value "=" for 'core.autoclrf

Then i did the `git config --get-all core.autocrlf` command to understand. And i'v seen that the value is not override when i set a new value, insted it's add a line with an other value.

I'v checked in my "/Git/etc/gitconfig" file to see what value was set to the autocrlf variable to see if i could change it directly from here but the value was "true".

So i don't understand where the values are stored.

Also i tried

```
    git config --unset-all core.autocrlf 
    git config --replace-all core.autocrlf
    git config --system --unset core.autocrlf
```

None of that worked. For the last one it was funny, i had a permission denied then did `chmod u+x gitconfig` but get a changing permission of gitconfig: permission denied.

So if you know how am i suppose to change the value of this boolean "core.autocrlf" so i can add my repository let me know.##

Comment: Try `git config --get-all --show-origin core.autocrlf`, it will show you where the config values are found. My guess is that the two instances are not in the same config file.

Comment: Also, if you want the setting to be global to your account, use `git config --global core.autocrlf false` will change your global Git config, while the default is to change only the sandbox you're in.

Comment: One more thing, you can manually edit the Git config file with a regular text editor. The easiest way out for you might be to just delete the bad config line and start again.

Comment: Also, `git config --edit` or `git config --global --edit` will fire up your configured editor (which you should first set with `git config` of course) on the local or global configuration file.

Comment: Thank you joanis i did `git config --get-all --show-origin core.autocrlf` and then with some `cd` and a `start .gitconfig` was able to open the file where the wrong value for autoclrf where stored. Also the `global` command is the thing i was missing here thanks a lot. Thanks Torek this will be very helpfull for editing my settings !

Answer (score 5):

Since you see a "bad boolean value", that means you are using Git 2.31+
Only that recent version has improved the error message, as [I reported here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66298344/6309).

It also means you have the `--show-scope` option (introduced with [Git 2.26, Q1 2020](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60286340/6309))

```sh
git config --get-all --show-origin --show-scope core.autocrlf
system  file:D:/newenv/prgs/gits/current/etc/gitconfig  true
global  file:C:/Users/vonc/.gitconfig  false
^^^^^^
(scope)
(shows you which git config --local/global/system to use)
```

I would not recommend using `--edit` and fiddling directly with a `.gitconfig` content. Using unset, then setting it again is safer.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, if you're on windows simple set it to true:

```
$ git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

If you're on macOS set it to false:

```
$ git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

Comment: ...please take a few seconds to proof-read your answer. You managed to typo both "true" _and_ "false"...

Answer (score 1):

Like OP I also managed to accidentally add a value into the `core.autocrlf` boolean - why this is even possible rather than just allowing `set` and `unset` for boolean config values, I'm not sure.

To fix the fatal error - which prevents `git` from being able to do anything at all, including reverting to an earlier snapshot - I did:

```
git config --edit
```

...and then simply removed the line containing `autocrlf` from my repo's `.git/config` file.

Answer (score 0):

Type this on your terminal

> git config --global -e

it will open `.gitconfig`
If you using windows, go to the folder

```
C:\Users\xxx_
```

You will find the `.gitconfig` file.

Answer (score 0):

I was lured here by "fatal: bad boolean config value".  I share my experience in case it helps others.

My problem was I'd erroneously typed `git config --system core.longpaths true~` (see the last character?).  When I tried to fix it with `git config --system core.longpaths true` all I got was `fatal: bad boolean config value 'true~' for 'core.longpaths'`

[joannis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3216427/joanis)' [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66891275/fatal-bad-boolean-config-value-for-core-autocrlf#comment118246745_66891275) was my saviour; `git config --get-all --show-origin core.longpaths` tells me which file I had to edit to fix my bad boolean

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem, when i was searching for warning of `clfr` to `lf` conversion warnings.

Solution:

```
$ git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ git config --local --replace-all core.autocrlf true
```

I used this command to get rid of the error: bad boolean value '=' core.autoclrf.