# I cannot add a github repository to Julia

Tags: julia, package-managers

I am following this [tutorial](https://benlauwens.github.io/ThinkJulia.jl/latest/book.html#chap04) to learn Julia and the idea is to add a Github repository to Julia:

`pkg> add https://github.com/BenLauwens/ThinkJulia.jl`

Unfortunately, it outputs a long error:

```
(v1.1) pkg> add https://github.com/BenLauwens/ThinkJulia.jl
  Updating git-repo `https://github.com/BenLauwens/ThinkJulia.jl`
ERROR: GitError(Code:ERROR, Class:Config, failed to map '--help')
Stacktrace:
 [1] macro expansion at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/LibGit2/src/error.jl:101 [inlined]
 [2] #checkout_tree#46(::LibGit2.CheckoutOptions, ::Function, ::LibGit2.GitRepo, ::LibGit2.GitTree) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/LibGit2/src/repository.jl:358
 [3] #checkout_tree at ./none:0 [inlined]
 [4] macro expansion at ./gcutils.jl:87 [inlined]
 [5] (::getfield(Pkg.Types, Symbol("##62#63")))(::LibGit2.GitTree) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/Pkg/src/Types.jl:780
 [6] with(::getfield(Pkg.Types, Symbol("##62#63")), ::LibGit2.GitTree) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/LibGit2/src/types.jl:1125
 [7] #handle_repos_add!#61(::Bool, ::Nothing, ::Function, ::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/Pkg/src/Types.jl:760
 [8] #handle_repos_add! at ./none:0 [inlined]
 [9] #add_or_develop#17(::Symbol, ::Bool, ::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}, ::Function, ::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/Pkg/src/API.jl:47
 [10] (::getfield(Pkg.API, Symbol("#kw##add_or_develop")))(::NamedTuple{(:mode,),Tuple{Symbol}}, ::typeof(Pkg.API.add_or_develop), ::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at ./none:0
 [11] do_add!(::Dict{Symbol,Any}, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}, ::Dict{Symbol,Any}) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/Pkg/src/REPLMode.jl:672
 [12] #invokelatest#1(::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}, ::Function, ::Any, ::Any, ::Vararg{Any,N} where N) at ./essentials.jl:742
 [13] invokelatest(::Any, ::Any, ::Vararg{Any,N} where N) at ./essentials.jl:741
 [14] do_cmd!(::Pkg.REPLMode.PkgCommand, ::REPL.LineEditREPL) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/Pkg/src/REPLMode.jl:563
 [15] #do_cmd#31(::Bool, ::Function, ::REPL.LineEditREPL, ::String) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/Pkg/src/REPLMode.jl:538
 [16] do_cmd at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/Pkg/src/REPLMode.jl:534 [inlined]
 [17] (::getfield(Pkg.REPLMode, Symbol("##53#56")){REPL.LineEditREPL,REPL.LineEdit.Prompt})(::REPL.LineEdit.MIState, ::Base.GenericIOBuffer{Array{UInt8,1}}, ::Bool) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/Pkg/src/REPLMode.jl:988
 [18] #invokelatest#1 at ./essentials.jl:742 [inlined]
 [19] invokelatest at ./essentials.jl:741 [inlined]
 [20] run_interface(::REPL.Terminals.TextTerminal, ::REPL.LineEdit.ModalInterface, ::REPL.LineEdit.MIState) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/REPL/src/LineEdit.jl:2273
 [21] run_frontend(::REPL.LineEditREPL, ::REPL.REPLBackendRef) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/REPL/src/REPL.jl:1035
 [22] run_repl(::REPL.AbstractREPL, ::Any) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/REPL/src/REPL.jl:192
 [23] (::getfield(Base, Symbol("##734#736")){Bool,Bool,Bool,Bool})(::Module) at ./client.jl:362
 [24] #invokelatest#1 at ./essentials.jl:742 [inlined]
 [25] invokelatest at ./essentials.jl:741 [inlined]
 [26] run_main_repl(::Bool, ::Bool, ::Bool, ::Bool, ::Bool) at ./client.jl:346
 [27] exec_options(::Base.JLOptions) at ./client.jl:284
 [28] _start() at ./client.jl:436
```

I don't understand why I am getting this error, so I would like to know any solution to this. By the way, I am using Julia 1.1 and I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have `git` installed in your system? Which OS are you running? Have a look at [the git website](https://git-scm.com/downloads)  on how to install it for different OS's.

Try running the command `Pkg.Status()` and see if you find anything meaningful. If you do so, I recommend checking as well the location `JULIA_PKGDIR` and removing the whole folder/git repo you 're trying to install.

As a last option you can create a new Julia home. In order to do so:

1. backup of your current home folder
2. delete your julia home (`.julia` in Unix-based systems)
3. run `Pkg.init`
4. Copy your old `REQUIRE` file to your new home
5. run `Pkg.update`
6. copy old packages to the new home as needed

Good luck!

Comment: I have `git` 2.22.1. By the way, are you sure your instructions are for Julia 1.1? `Pkg.init` doesn't work in Julia 1.1, `JULIA_PKGDIR` is not a thing in Julia 1.1, the command should be `Pkg.status()`. Anyway... I have followed your instructions and I still have the problem.

Comment: Which OS are you running? Try `Pkg.update()`. What do you get?

Comment: I have Ubuntu 16.04 and after Pkg.update(), I get:                                                    ```Cloning default registries into `~/.julia`
   Cloning registry from "https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git"
ERROR: failed to clone from https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git, error: GitError(Code:ERROR, Class:Config, failed to map '--help')
```

Comment: What happens if you try `git clone https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git` from the command line?

Comment: Now I understand my problem, it was something related to `git`. I have added my answer to show why.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so the problem is related to some configuration with `git`. If you try:

`git clone https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git`

it shows an error:

```
Clonando en 'General'...
fatal: mal valor de config numérica '--help' para 'core.autocrlf': unidad inválida
```

which translates to:

```
Cloning 'General'
fatal: bad numeric config value 'auto' for 'core.autocrlf
```

Following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21328799/9655789), I wrote in the terminal:

`git config --global --replace-all core.autocrlf false`

and problem solved. Now I can add repositories and packages to Julia.

Comment: I would appreciate if you mark my answer as helpful, as I located the problem in your `git` :) Ta

Comment: This command 'git config --global --replace-all core.autocrlf false' worked for me