# Powershell Get-FileHash returning different checksums for same file

Tags: powershell, cryptography

I'm trying to figure out what could cause Powershell's Get-FileHash to start returning a different checksum for an unchanged file but I can't find any information about how Get-FileHash works

I'm using the code

```
$hash = Get-FileHash -Path $filePath -Algorithm MD5
```

The file that is being checked is coming out of git (as is the powershell script), so I can see it hasn't been altered in months, but suddenly we're getting a different hash returned

The VM this code is running on was recreated yesterday, but i've re-built the server several times over the last few months without this occurring

Is it possible that a .net update is causing this issue, or could a change of architecture have caused it?

Answer (score 1):

> The file that is being checked is coming out of git

Could this be because GIT converts line ending during checkout (`core.autocrlf` option)?

Relevant question: [How line ending conversions work with git core.autocrlf between different operating systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206843/how-line-ending-conversions-work-with-git-core-autocrlf-between-different-operat)

Comment: I've checked and the options are the same before and after the VM re-build