# How to change the behavior of git status showing modified files which are eventually not committed?

Tags: windows, git, end-of-line, core.autocrlf

I am working in a windows-only working environment with developers using all kinds of tools to edit their files. We are using `.git` along with the atlassian stack to version our code. I like almost all of it.

I have just recently finished fighting a long and hard fight to wrap my head around how and why git interprets line endings and what `core.autocrlf` does. We've decided to use `core.autocrlf true` and all is almost well.

I would LOVE to know how to change this behavior of `git status`:

- I have a file with `CRLF` line endings.
- I change the line endings to `LF`

  ```
  $ git status
  On branch somebranch
  Changes not staged for commit:
      (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
      (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

  modified:   Src/the_file_i_changed_to_LF.js
  ```
- But then...

  ```
  $ git commit -a
  warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Src/the_file_i_changed_to_LF.js.
  The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
  On branch somebranch
  nothing to commit, working directory clean
  ```

To this one:

- I have a file with `CRLF` line endings.
- I change the line endings to `LF`

  ```
  $ git status
  On branch somebranch
  nothing to commit, working directory clean
  ```
- which makes sense since nothing will get committed anyway.

Is this possible?

I believe the possible duplicate does not hold the answer I am looking for. I would like to emphasize that I do (think I) know what my setting `core.autocrlf true` does and want to keep it that way. What I'm interested in is either not detecting changes in `git status` which will not be committed anyway, or understanding why this is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

When you set `core.autocrlf true` all files in your working directory will have `CRLF` line ending (regard less of the actual line ending in the repository). For most windows users this is good enough.

From your question I understand you want to have your working directory files (=local file) with `LF`. So, here you should be using `core.autocrlf input`. This will give you the exact line ending as in the repository (but still it will make sure all check-ins are made with `LF`).

Read more about the difference of true, false, input in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206843/how-line-ending-conversions-work-with-git-core-autocrlf-between-different-operat).