# Git commit change video file

Tags: git, video, line-endings

When I commit and push changes, my MP4 and video files get changed.
I tried this on MAC and WIN, and is same on both.
My remote repository is BitBucked, but problem is located in my local repository.

For example, when committing file about 4MB, file in repository is about 60 bytes smaller then original. I looked into it and some 0D are missing.

This sounded like  CRLF, LF conversion, but after experimenting with
`core.autocrlf` params, nothing is changed.

Is there some configuration I am missing?

UPDATE

Here are files: 
Original: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-30m3j9bgwrcUN0OEdiT2lid28

When I download it from BB:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-30m3j9bgwrOXN0NVBLTzhHTGM

Here is .gitattributes

```
# All text files should have the "lf" (Unix) line endings
* text eol=lf

# Explicitly declare text files you want to always be normalized and converted
# to native line endings on checkout.
*.java text
*.js text
*.css text
*.html text

# Denote all files that are truly binary and should not be modified.
*.png binary
*.jpg binary
*.jar binary
*.pdf binary
*.eot binary
*.ttf binary
*.gzip binary
*.gz binary
*.ai binary
*.eps binary
*.swf binary
```

Answer (score 1):

I added

```
*.mp4 binary
```

to .gitattribute

And now it works!

Answer (score 0):

The main configuration you need to set is:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

Then clone again your BitBucket repo.

That way, you will avoid an automatic eol conversion on *all* files.

If you still need eol conversion for *some* files, set a [`core.eol` directive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3209806/6309) in a `.gitattributes` file.

Comment: It was already set to false. I cloned repo again, and still having issue.

Comment: So in that repo, a `git config -l | grep autocrlf` would show it as false? Is there any `.gitattributes` files with a `core.eol` directive in them?

Comment: git config -l | grep autocrlf
core.autocrlf=false
I just added an example files