# What is difference between autocrlf and eol

Tags: git, gitattributes

I'm reading [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) about `.gitattributes` to fix my problems with mixed line endings and find out that there is two similar settings.

AUTOCRLF:

> End-of-line conversion While Git normally leaves file contents alone,
>   it can be configured to normalize line endings to LF in the repository
>   and, optionally, to convert them to CRLF when files are checked out.
>
> If you simply want to have CRLF line endings in your working directory
>   regardless of the repository you are working with, you can set the
>   config variable "core.autocrlf" without using any attributes.
>
> [core]    autocrlf = true This does not force normalization of text
>   files, but does ensure that text files that you introduce to the
>   repository have their line endings normalized to LF when they are
>   added, and that files that are already normalized in the repository
>   stay normalized.

And EOL:

> This attribute sets a specific line-ending style to be used in the
>   working directory. It enables end-of-line conversion without any
>   content checks, effectively setting the text attribute.
>
> Set to string value "crlf" This setting forces Git to normalize line
>   endings for this file on checkin and convert them to CRLF when the
>   file is checked out.
>
> Set to string value "lf" This setting forces Git to normalize line
>   endings to LF on checkin and prevents conversion to CRLF when the file
>   is checked out.
>
> **Backwards compatibility with crlf attribute** 
>   For backwards compatibility, the crlf attribute is interpreted as follows:
>
> crlf      text
>
> -crlf     -text
>
> crlf=input    eol=lf

It seems that both are doing the same, but there is something about `compatibility`. Does it mean, that `autocrlf` is deprecated and the new flavor is `eol` or something? I currently have a repository with multiple corrupted files which I want to convert into `crlf` representation. And you see that documentation confuse us instead of clarify things.

What should I apply in this situation?

Comment: [This question is similar but I'm not sure if it's a duplicate.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206843/how-line-ending-conversions-work-with-git-core-autocrlf-between-different-operat) On the other hand, [the answer from VonC](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3209806/2274224) explains the difference between `core.eol` and `core.autocrlf` quite detailed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rather than directly answering the question itself—see [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3209806/1256452) to the linked question for that—let's concentrate on this:

> I currently have a repository with multiple corrupted files which I want to convert into crlf representation.

First, let's note that none of these options can *change* any existing commit.  This is a fundamental Git property: once made, no existing commit can be altered.  What you can do is make *new* commits.  That's usually not too big a deal since usually we just want *new* stuff to be correct (but see `git filter-branch`, which copies commits after applying filters to their contents, and can be used to re-copy an entire repository: the new repo is no longer compatible with the old one, but you can "fix history" this way).

Next, I think this is the key to understanding all of these end of line / CRLF attribute options: **transformations are applied to files when they move into or out of the index.**

Remember that Git's index is where you build the *next* commit.  The contents of the index are initially the same as whatever commit is current: you run `git checkout master`, for instance, and Git resolves the name `master` to a commit-ID and copies that particular commit to your work-tree—but the copy goes *through* the index.

In other words, Git first finds that file `foo.txt` is in the commit (and needs to be extracted).  So Git moves that version of `foo.txt` to the index.  The index's version *exactly matches* the `HEAD` commmit's version.  Git does not apply any filters to the index version, nor change any line endings.

*Once the index version is updated,* Git copies that version of the file *from* the index to the work-tree.<sup>1</sup>  Some transformations take place *now*, during this extraction process.  If there is a smudge filter, Git applies it now.  If there are line-ending conversions to make, Git applies those now.

The work-tree file may, during this process, become *different from* the index version.  Now Git has a problem, because now the file is "dirty" (modified in the work-tree).  This is where things get particularly confusing, although most of the time, the details here are invisible.

Eventually, after working with your work-tree, you may run `git add` on some file path-name (or use `git add -a` or whatever to add many files).  This copies the file from the work-tree, into the index.<sup>2</sup>  More transformations happen now, during this copy: if there is a clean filter, Git applies it now.  If there are line-ending conversions to make, Git applies them now.

In other words, after `git add`-ing these files, the *index* version may not match the work-tree version.  However, Git marks the index version as "matching" anyway.  A `git status` will skip right over the work-tree version, because Git now claims that the index version matches the work-tree version.  It *sort of does*, because the index version matches what *would be added* if you ran `git add` again.

The actual implementation uses time stamps, usually with one-second resolution.  Git will continue to believe that the index version matches the work-tree version unless and until the OS touches the time-stamp on the work-tree version of the file.  *This is true even if you change the set of filters and/or line-ending conversions to apply.*  Git doesn't realize that you have changed the way the line endings should work, or changed the "clean" filter to do something different: it just sees that the index's "cache" aspect says "I match work-tree version time-stamp *T*".  As long as the work-tree version's time-stamp is still *T*, the file must be "clean".

Hence, to update these things after changing any text-conversion settings, you need to make Git realize that the file is not clean.  You can `touch <path>` to set a new time-stamp of "now", which won't match the older time stamp in the index.  Now `git add -a` (or whatever) will scan as usual, but since the time stamps don't match, it will find the file this time, and will re-filter it to add it to the index.

**Again, these transformations occur when you `git add` the file.**

---

Normally, on a Windows-like system, your goal here will be to take LF-only repository-format files and turn them into CR-LF files for Windows to deal with.  That transformation occurs on the way *out* of the index, *to* the work-tree: i.e., during `git checkout`.  Then you would want to transform these CR-LF work-tree files into LF-only format during the `git add` process, so that the in-repository form is the way Linux (and Linus Torvalds and hence Git :-) ) prefer them.  But you *can* store them inside the repository in CR-LF format, if you really want to annoy all the Unix/Linux folks.  It's all a matter of which transforms, if any, you apply at which steps: `git checkout` time, and `git add` time.

The `.gitattributes` file specifies which transforms to apply to which files.  The `core.autocrlf` and `core.eol` settings *don't:* Git must make its best guess about which files get which transformations at which step.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, all that's in the index is the hash ID of the file.  The file itself is stored as a Git *blob* object in the repository database.  Just as with commit objects, these blob objects are immutable.  That's *why* it cannot be changed in the index: it's really just a hash ID.

<sup>2</sup>The `git add` process simply writes a *new* blob, with the new blob written after any filtering.  If the new blob exactly matches some existing blob, bit-for-bit, the new blob re-uses the existing blob's database entry and hash ID, and is not actually saved—the existing blob suffices.  If not, the blob's data gets stored as a new file, with a new ID.  It's the new hash ID that goes into the index.

Comment: Great answer, but `core.autocrlf` in `gitattributes` and eol settings (`*.txt text eol=crlf`) are designed for very this issue - EOL transformation during extracting out and adding in index. I just was confused about two settings for same thing. After some research I found out that latter setting just allowing more precise configuration. You are configuring files by extension rather than doing it for all files in repository. `autocrlf` already corrupted some files in my repository (`xls` for example), when I can mark them as `binary` with `eol`

Comment: If you use `*.blah text=auto`, then yes, you are doing it by extension (and auto-classification). If you use `foo.* text=auto` you are doing it by prefix, and if you use `* text=auto` you are explicitly calling for it globally, rather than depending on `core.autocrlf` (whose setting is outside the Git-controlled files within the repository). I think the fact that `core.autocrlf` is not part of the version-controlled files can be a key reason to use it, or to avoid it (personally I avoid it just as I avoid Windows :-) ).

Comment: I expected that `core.autocrlf` can be stored in `gitattributes` just like `text=...`. However, I didn't try it and stucked with new shiny eol.

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy: no, `core.autocrlf` is a `git config` setting, and those cannot be stored in the repository.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Then, the last question: is there any difference between `-text` and `binary` settings here? Because I found the former on git documentation page while the latter is used in every `.gitattributes` I see.

Comment: According to `gitattributes` docs, `binary` is a "macro" that expands to `-text -diff`. This is not directly related, but there are two places where the literal string `binary` is meaningful, inside a diff driver (see the discussion near the end of the `textconv` section) and as a merge driver (see "Built-in merge drivers").