# Git for Visual Studio lists unchanged files in 'changes'?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, whitespace

I'm using **Visual Studio 2015**,and **Git extension for Visual Studio**.

What makes me confused is when I pull code from servers, and Visual Studio's **Team Explorer** lists so many unchanged files in the 'Changes' area,
 after I clicked 'Compare with Unmodified', it just shows nothing different.

But when I use **git bash** git diff command, the changes are whitespaces or empty line.

I don't change any code, how I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Could it be line endings?

Comment: Lasse, I already set the core.autocrlf=true, but it not help.

Answer (score 0):

> I already set the `core.autocrlf=true`, but it not help

Actually, the right setting would be:

```
 git config --global core.autocrlf=false
```

(See "[How line ending conversions work with `git core.autocrlf` between different operating systems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14039909/6309)" for more)

Then try again to *clone* the repo elsewhere, and then to pull new commits. 
No additional diff should show up.