# Line endings are not following default settings in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatting, line-endings, eol

When I try to push to GitHub, everytime I keep getting such warnings:

```
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in app/bingey-api/models/user.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
```

Even though I changed my line endings setting to "/n" in these places:

User -> Text Editor -> Files -> Eol:

[image]

Also Workspace -> Text Editor -> Files -> Eol:

[image]

Also my ESLint options file has default line ending "\n":

[image]

And Prettier is also configured to default "\n" endline symbol:

[image]

This is weird, maybe someone knows where else should I change settings?
Thank you.

Comment: You should maybe have a look at your git core.autocrlf parameter. I don't think this is related to your vs code configuration. You can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206843/how-line-ending-conversions-work-with-git-core-autocrlf-between-different-operat).

Comment: Thank you, this parameter was set to false. Setting it to true fixed my issue. Look at question update for more info.

Comment: Setting it to true also fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FOUND SOLUTION:

In VS Code go to Terminal -> New Terminal and try to look what is the value of your core.autocrlf parameter like that:

```
 git config --global --get core.autocrlf
```

If nothing shows it means that it is set to default value (which is false)
Otherwise, set it to false:

```
 git config --global core.autocrlf false
```