# Why is 'Updating the Git index failed' displayed

Tags: windows, git, newline, core.autocrlf

I am using Windows. When staging files I get this error.

`Updating the Git index failed. A rescan will be automatically started to resynchronize git-gui.`

followed by a list of files which have been converted from LF to CRLF

After a lot of reading up on the CRLF / LF issue with Git usage cross platform, I more or less understand what is going on, and I am trying to determine which autocrlf setting is best for me, but I cant understand why Git says that Updating the index failed. My understanding is that it has converted the EOF's so what is the problem with that and why is it telling me that updating the index has failed. Do I need to fix something ( other than picking an appropriate autocrlf setting) or can I just proceed

I then have two options Continue and Unlock Index, what do these mean and what is the best course of action.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LF will be replaced by CRLF in git - What is that and is it important?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834014/lf-will-be-replaced-by-crlf-in-git-what-is-that-and-is-it-important)

Comment: I wonder how many collective hours programming humanity has lost to worrying about line endings? If only [Gary Kildall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gary_Kildall) had just gone with LF in the first place.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

Has always been my recommendation (see "[Git 1.6.4 beta on Windows (msysgit) - Unix or DOS line termination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249932/git-1-6-4-beta-on-windows-msysgit-unix-or-dos-line-termination/1250133#1250133)").

However, in your case, you can "Continue", but this warning is there to mention the conversion of certain files might not be reversible:

```
core.safecrlf
```

> If true, makes git check if converting CRLF is reversible when end-of-line conversion is active. Git will verify if a command modifies a file in the work tree either directly or indirectly. For example, committing a file followed by checking out the same file should yield the original file in the work tree. If this is not the case for the current setting of `core.autocrlf`, git will reject the file.
>   The variable can be set to "warn", in which case git will only warn about an irreversible conversion but continue the operation.

If you don't want to see this warning, as explained in [this thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.msysgit/7232), you can set `core.safecrlf` to `false`.

You could also stash your files through the tools menu of git gui, and add some options to those tools with, for instance, this [git config file](https://github.com/adamfranco/dotfiles/blob/master/.gitconfig).
The interest is that, for each tool, you can add:

```
guitool.<name>.norescan
```

> Don’t rescan the working directory for changes after the tool finishes execution.

---

> Could you please elaborate a bit on Unlock Index

you can see that message in the [`index.tcl` git-gui script](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-gui/lib/index.tcl#L4-L57): it removes the index.lock file the git-gui creates when manipulating the index.
You can see more at the ["lockfile API" documentation page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/api-lockfile.txt):

> **Mutual exclusion**.
>   When we write out a new index file, first we create a new file `$GIT_DIR/index.lock`, write the new contents into it, and rename it to the final destination `$GIT_DIR/index`.
>   We try to create the `$GIT_DIR/index.lock` file with `O_EXCL` so that we can notice and fail when somebody else is already trying to update the index file.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer, but you mention warning a couple of times, but that's exactly my problem, it doesnt imply it's a warning but an error.`Updating the Git index failed` ... or am I misinterpreting this?

Comment: @byronyasgur the thread I mention in the answer refers to this message as a "warning", I suppose because it doesn't *fail* completly the git command. It only interrupts it, asking you for a choice (unless you specify "`norescan`" or `core.safecrlf` to `false`)

Comment: I'm beginning to understand. Can you explain the difference between those two choices or point me to a resource that does, I can't seem to find out what is meant by Unlock and Continue in this context.

Comment: @byronyasgur http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2008/8/12/2901814 I think if you don't "Continue", that means you don't want the EOL conversion to go on, which means Git has to release its lock on the files in the index it was suppose to update.

Comment: I'm thinking that false is the setting for me anyway so AFAICS it becomes moot for me.

Comment: @byronyasgur ok, sounds easier that way.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit on _Unlock Index_ so this very comprehensive answer is complete ?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D I have edited my answer to detail the Unlock Index step

Comment: Grr - it seems `Unlock Index` does exactly what `Continue` does - $#@$^

Answer (score 3):

I also ran into this even tho my `core.autocrlf` setting is already `false` and `core.safecrlf` is unset. I suspect the culprit is the config setting `diff.astextplain.textconv`.

When I ran `git config --list`, the following line was shown in the output:

```
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
```

I don't think this setting is actually related to the warning/error but it inspired me to look into text conversion that might be being done. After a little spelunking online and in my repo, I discovered the following line in my repo's *.gitattributes* file:

```
* text=auto
```

[I probably got the *.gitattributes* file from GitHub.]

Given that only the above line was un-commented in it, and further that dealing with 'automagic' line-ending conversions has **always** been a headache, I opted to remove that file from my repo. After doing so, staging the same files no longer prompted me with the "Updating the Git index failed" warning/error.

Answer (score 3):

**A more direct answer:**

Git is telling you that your current workspace file has different line-endings than what it expected.  It sounds like you've already read up on that.  Personally, I think the **best** solution is to define your desired line-endings in a .gitattributes file:
*.py text eol=lf
*.bat text eol=crlf

**Now for the question that everyone refused to answer:**

What does "Unlock Index" do in the Git Gui?  It removes the ".git/index.lock" file so that you can run other git commands before continuing. The Git GUI will create this file when it starts a Git command so that no other git processes will interfere and corrupt your local repository.  It removes the index.lock once it is complete.

**Bottom line:**
Clicking "Unlock Index" is not going to do anything useful here, and you should only click it if you are debugging the Git Gui itself.  It's so rarely used that most people don't even know what it does, nor do they care.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:** This warning means that git might return you a text file in Windows-style despite you having checked in a text file in UNIX-style.

UNIX and Windows differ in how they save line breaks in text files. Wikipedia has a [list of line breaks on different OSes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representation)

The warning you get is reproducible if you do the following on Windows:

- Create a git repository in an empty directory
- Create a commit representing the initial, empty state of the repo:

  ```
  git commit --allow-empty -m "initial commit"
  ```
- use `git config core.autocrlf` and `git config core.safecrlf` to verify that `autocrlf` is set to `true` and `safecrlf` is unset (no output). If this is not the case, use the following commands to set them

  ```
  git config core.autocrlf true
  git config --unset core.safecrlf
  ```
- Use [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org) to write a text file called `text.txt` in UNIX format. Write a file which has at least one line break. This is how you select UNIX line endings: 
  [image: Notepad++ with the menu Edit - EOL Conversion opened]
- `git add text.txt`. You get the warning message

  > warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in text.txt.
  >   The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
- Commit the text file: `git commit -m "add file with UNIX endings"
- Now see how the file looks like if you check it out from the tree. First, check out the version before you created the file (go 1 commit back). The file `text.txt` vanishes from the working directory:

  ```
  git checkout ~1
  ```
- Now, restore the version after you created the file

  ```
  git checkout master
  ```

The file `text.txt` is restored. But open it in Notepad++ and check the line ending format in the bottom status line of Notepad++:

[image: The restored file which has now Windows-style CRLF endings]

The file you checked out has Windows-style line endings, yet the file you commited had UNIX-style file endings! This is what the warning message is about: **The settings `core.autocrlf=true` together with `core.safecrlf=<unset>` mean that the files you get restored from the tree might be different from the files you checked in, because they might have different file endings.**