# Disable code formatting when working with an SCM

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, code-formatting, pull-request

I'm currentely working on a *Git* pull request for some repository. I have run through typical steps: fork -> add some changes -> commit -> push to forked repo and then create a PR.

I'm quite familiar with Git and have already created many PRs, but a particular project starts to cause some formatting issues.

When I pushed the update branch and went to github UI to check my PR changes, I have see many many diff changes that seems related to *Intellij IDEA* which formatted my code. Here goes a sample:
[image]

What those sections refer to? Why is Intellij removing an are and adding absolutely the same one so it is marked as a diff?

Actually those changes makes my PR too hard to read, even for me and I'm sure that project owner won't accept such an horor.

So my question is, *how to deal with such situations*? Can I disable code formatting and work on my PR? Is there an other hint to do so?

I'm addressing my question to Intellij + Git experts, so please suggest if there is some practices (good) I should follow.

Regards.

Comment: A lot of tools offer an option to ignore whitespace changes. This can be activated to be able to concentrate on substantial changes. I would review all whitespace changes at least superficially though.

Comment: Can you list one of those tools? This seems too hazardous for me because I worked on a lot of PRs before and have never met such an issue as I always managed to adjust my ide inetation rules to much those for the repo I will commit to.

Comment: I'm sure IDEA can. Other than that: gitk, meld, Eclipse and a lot of git commands accept the `-w` option to accomplish that. But I think I misread your question; these options are useful for the person merging the pull request. Your question is more suited for an IDEA expert.

Comment: Just what I thought, my issue should be considered from a developer view not the commiter one.
Thanks for mentionning some of those options :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this is not an IDE issue, so Intellij IDE had nothing to do with it.
The problem was actually due to **how Git handled line endings**.

Following some SO posts and tried multiple solutions, I ended up with [@VonC suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1250133/2106516) to disable line endings modifications and where he stated:

> I would insist on not trying to convert anything automagically, the side-effects are just too important (in term of potential merging conflict, especially on distributed development with different environments)

So simply executing below command will prevent Git from changing anything:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

Then had to clean
<sup>(I have chosen to grab the remote branch again to start all from scratch and with a clean working copy)</sup> my working directory.