# Any way to put my hook to github repo?

Tags: github, hook

Can I achieve it so that after pulling a repo from github the hooks has existed in `.git/hooks` directory?

Answer (score 5):

Not directly, as that would represent a security risk (you don't know what those hook scripts are doing)

You can try and:

- version a file (or files) representing your hooks in your git repo
- [version a `.gitattribute`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316728/6309) declaring a [content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10571580/6309) (`smudge` script), which will trigger on `git checkout`.
- in that `smudge` script, copy those files into your `.git/hooks`

[image: smudge]

<sup>(image from "[Customizing Git - Git Attributes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion)", from "[Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/)")</sup>

But even in that case, you would need to activate that `smudge` filter with a `git config` command first (which can be a global config, so done *before* cloning the repo)

```
git config --global filter.hooks.smudge 'script_to_copy_hooks'
```