# Gitlab pre-commit hook

Tags: hook, gitlab, pre-commit-hook

I would like to use pre-commit hook in gitlab. I doing everything like in documentation: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/administration/custom_hooks.html

In custom_hooks directory I've created pre-commit file with folowing content:

```
#!/bin/bash

exit 1
```

Hook is never triggered, couse i can commit.

When i do the same with pre-receive hook - everything works good.

If Gitlab doesnt't let to use pre-commit hook?

Comment: Solved - pre-commit is a client-side hook and should be stored in .git/hooks location on client machine (in my case on Windows). It’s important to note that client-side hooks are not copied when you clone a repository. I will try do everything using server-side hooks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As explained in [Customizing Git - Git Hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Client-Side-Hooks), a client-side hook won't be used on the server.

I explained before why it is not possible to include hooks in a clone:

- "[why it is not possible to git add .git/hooks/my-hook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5165299/6309)"
- "[Any way to put my hook to github repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34013278/6309)"

[Since GitLab 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24155063/6309), you can [set custom Git Hooks](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/administration/custom_hooks.md) for server-side hooks.

> Git natively supports hooks that are executed on different actions. Examples of server-side git hooks include pre-receive, post-receive, and update
>
> Normally, Git hooks are placed in the repository or project's hooks directory. GitLab creates a symlink from each project's hooks directory to the gitlab-shell hooks directory for ease of maintenance between gitlab-shell upgrades