How to configure pre-commit hooks in GITLAB?

Will gitlab creates a temporary commit_msg_file once git commit or git commit -m is given?
how to configure pre-commit hooks, so that once the developes gives the commit message, that needs to be validated at command prompt?


Something similar has been asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39786724/gitlab-pre-commit-hook


No. Git Hooks functionality is from Git itself, not GitLab.
You can create a pre-commit file under your project (e.g, pre-commit.sh), create a symbolically link of it:

ln -s $PWD/pre-commit.sh .git/hooks/pre-commit

For commit message, try this:
cd path/to/your/repo/.git/hooks
touch commit-msg
# make sure the new file is executable
chmod +x commit-msg

Then write the validation like:
#!/bin/sh
# commit-msg hook script to validate the commit message

COMMIT_MSG_FILE=$1
COMMIT_MSG=$(cat $COMMIT_MSG_FILE)

# Check if the commit message contains the keyword "BUGFIX"
if [[ ! $COMMIT_MSG =~ BUGFIX ]]; then
  echo "Error: Commit message must contain 'BUGFIX'"
  exit 1
fi


but this idea will still push commit message to GITLAB. How do i dont allow invalid commits from the command prompt itslef

can you havea  look here

please create a file named 'commit-msg' in hooks dir.

.since git/hooks is a hidden file, these changes are limited to my local.

also, if anyother user clones the repo, these changes arenot valid. How can i over come this?

@Vandana Pre-commit hooks are local. They have nothing to do with gitlab, github or any other distant platform.

@RomainValeri Thanks for the clarification. Is there any way i can do this differently so that i achieve my requiremnts

The commit message shall start with ‘#’, followed by 7 digits, A Space, & 3-400 characters.
eg: #1234567 Implementation
#1234567 is the Ticket ID from Code beamer.
git commit operation should be valid, only is this Ticket ID is in OPEN status in code beamer.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12222186/are-git-hooks-pushed-to-the-remote-when-i-git-push
