# How important is to enforce the "linebreak-style" rule in ESlint? Can I just turn it off?

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, eslint

I've created a Node.js module which I'm gonna be open-sourcing soon. I originally developed it on Linux and I decided to test it on Windows before publishing it. When I ran ESLint on Windows I noticed I had a huge amount of linting errors which were all the same:

```
error  Expected linebreaks to be 'LF' but found 'CRLF'  linebreak-style
```

I read in a couple of places that these linebreaks were inserted by Git when I cloned the repo on Windows. I also read that it is possible to turn off this rule in the eslint config file. Is it safe to do this? or is there a "best practice" regarding this rule? (considering this will be an open source project and hopefully others will be contributing to it)

Any advice or feedback will be appreciated.

Comment: I believe Git has some options to deal with this (i.e., to handle it prior to linting). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418975/how-to-change-line-ending-settings).

Answer (score 2):

Try to re-clone your repo after typing:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

That should avoid Git converting your eol (end of lines) from LF to CRLF automatically on checkout.
Then your linter should find the expected eol.

Note: I have been advocating for that setting to be false by default for years: see "[Git: Unix or DOS line termination](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1250133/6309)".