# Git renormalise not working on an old repo

Tags: git, core.autocrlf

I've inherited a repo that's been developed on Windows and has always been hosted on Windows. Historically, `autocrlf` has been disabled, so our main repo will have crlf line endings.

However, we're moving to more of a cross-platform situation, so we want to enable `autocrlf`.

I've tried running `git add --renormalise .` [as per these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156694/git-how-to-renormalize-line-endings-in-all-files-in-all-revisions) but when I try and commit it, there are no changes, presumably because they're already CRLF and I'm on Windows, so I can't push it to have it renormalised on the remote.

How would I go about doing this? Do I need to check it out on a Unix machine then do a push?

Comment: Do you have an `.gitattributes` (https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) file? I'm not 100% sure it's required for that but maybe it's some clue.

Comment: We don't yet, we were planning on adding it after we'd renormalised on a branch and checked everything was okay

Comment: I'm not expert on that but what I would do is to add `.gitattributes` in which all text files are explicitly stated as such so git knows which files to renormalise. Then commit the file and then `git add --renormalise .`. I don't know if all the steps are necessary but I know that the full procedure always worked for me.

Comment: @PiotrSiupa - I will try it and get back to you tomorrow :) thank you my friend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`git add --renormalize .`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt---renormalize) I mention with [Git 2.16+ (Q1 2018)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47580886/6309) works in collaboration with git config and `.gitattributes`

Add and commit a `.gitattributes` with:

```
*.txt text eol=lf
```

Then add (with the renormalize option), and commit if needed.

Cloning that repository (with the `.gitattributes` directives in it) will result in `.txt` file keeping one consistent EOL (here LF).
Since most Windows IDE/editor know how to preserve LF, that is more convenient for cross-platform development.
And that allows you to keep `git config --global core.autocrl false`, which [I have always recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1250133/6309).

Comment: Having LF line endings will break some things on Windows though. Sure, IDEs can cope, but not everything can.

Comment: @ScottishTapWater You do not have to specify LF for *all* txt file. The idea with a .gitattributes file is to version the directives you need for exactly the files you want managed. As opposed to `core.autocrlf`, which impact *everything*.

Comment: Sure, but what's wrong with just committing LF and checking out CRLF on Windows but LF and LF on Linux? That seems like the optimal solution here. I don't really want to rely on everyone always opening these files in an IDE... The second someone opens something in notepad it'll change the line endings

Comment: @ScottishTapWater I would recommend to *not* depend on automagic transformation: pick one EOL style for specific files or group of files and make sure the development environment does not impact it. Even the good old Notepad understand LF now, as I [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2825829/6309), for [Windows 10 2018.09+](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2018/05/08/extended-eol-in-notepad/).

Comment: I would hope that a well tested, fairly old feature in git works after it's existed for this long... Good news about Notepad though... If Powershell can handle it too... you might be right